# React-Navigation 3: Open modal with createBottomTabNavigator and createStackNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

*I know this question has been asked before, but only for older versions of react-navigation. Since then a few things have changed. `createBottomTabNavigator` makes it much faster to create a bottom navigator and the function `jumpToIndex()` doesn't exist anymore.*

My Question is how to create an Instagram-like bottom tab, where the first, second, fourth and fifth navigation buttons act like usual tab navigators and the middle button (`screen3`) opens the modal `screen3Modal`.

I have tried it in react-navigation 3.x.x, using `createBottomTabNavigator` and `createStackNavigator`.

```
import React, { Component, } from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, } from 'react-navigation';
import { Screen1, Screen2, Screen3, Screen4, Screen5 } from './screens';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  screen1: { screen: Screen1, },
  screen2: { screen: Screen2, },
  screen3: { 
    screen: () => null, 
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      tabBarOnPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('screen3Modal')
    })
  },
  screen4: { screen: Screen4, },
  screen5: { screen: Screen5, },
});

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: TabNavigator },
  screen3Modal: { screen: Screen3, },
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

const StackNavigatorContainer = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <StackNavigatorContainer />;
  }
}
```

This code creates the tab navigation and modal navigation. The modal can be opened from another screen, but it doesn't work from within the tab navigator. I get the errormessage `undefined is not an object (evaluating  '_this.props.navigation')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a relatively easy solution:
Hide the original navigation bar with `display:"none"`

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    screen1: Screen1,
    screen2: Screen2,
    screen4: Screen4,
    screen5: Screen5,
  }, {
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: { display: "none", }
    }
  },
);

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: TabNavigator,
    screen3: Screen3
  }, {
    mode: 'modal',
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

And create a new navigation bar on each screen

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", height: 50, justifyContent: "space-evenly", alignItems: "center", width: "100%" }}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("screen1")}><Text>1</Text></TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("screen2")}><Text>2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("screen3")}><Text>3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("screen4")}><Text>4</Text></TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("screen5")}><Text>5</Text></TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: Rock solid solution. How would you display the active tab though? In your example there is no active tab concept.

Comment: That's not a good solution, you're only supposed to have single Bottom Navigation component throughout the app. Adding the same component to all screens will make if flicker on navigation, and it won't look & feel like "Tabs" anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap everything inside the same StackNavigator, that way you can navigate to other routes easily. Here i'm passing the screen3 as default route, but you can change that to whatever you'd like.

```
import React, { Component, } from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, } from 'react-navigation';
import { Screen1, Screen2, Screen3, Screen4, Screen5 } from './screens';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  screen1: { screen: Screen1, },
  screen2: { screen: Screen2, },
  screen3: { screen: () => null, }, //this.props.navigation.navigate('screen3Modal')
  screen4: { screen: Screen4, },
  screen5: { screen: Screen5, },
});

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: TabNavigator },
  screen3Modal: { screen: Screen3, },
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'screen3Modal',
});

const StackNavigatorContainer = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <StackNavigatorContainer />;
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you navigate to the modal? 
I have tried `tabBarOnPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('screen3Modal')` but i get an error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')`

Comment: from which screen you are trying to navigate? do you have your constructor(props) {super(props)} set?

Comment: I have edited my post above. I hope it's better understandable now.
The initial screen should be `Home` (the tab navigator) and when `screen3` is pressed a modal should open, which covers the whole page and hides the bottom navigator.

no, I don't have it set. Everything I have is in the code above.

Comment: Ah ok, wasnt that clear before, have you checked this answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024006/open-a-modal-on-bottomtabnavigator-click-react-native

I believe that what you are trying to do is not possible the way you are doing it

Comment: I have tried a new solution:

I created a new screen which only purpose is to open the modal on `componentWillMount`.
now I could simply open this new screen with the tab navigator like in the link you sent me, but this creates a few other problems. 
Wouldn't it be much cleaner to use `tabBarOnPress` and `forceUpdate` this new screen which then should on load open the modal?
If it is possible, how should I use the `forceUpdate` function? I didn't get it to work.

Comment: I have found such an easy solution. I'm gonna post it later

Answer (score 1):

Well I have spent hours upon hours to solve this problem.

Here's fully working & tested solution:

1. Set up your app container by including tabs stack & to be opened modal navigation stack:

```
  const FinalTabsStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      tabs: TabNavigator,
      screen1: Screen1Navigator,
    }, {
      mode: 'modal',
    }
  )
```

2. Create app container with that tabs stack per [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html) guide
3. Inside the `TabNavigator` in the `createBottomTabNavigator` return null component for specific tab (screen3) (to turn off navigation by react-navigator) and handle the tab manually inside the `defaultNavigationOptions` by creating custom component for it.

```
  const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    screen1: Screen1Navigator,
    screen2: Screen2Navigator,
    screen3: () => null,
    screen4: Screen4Navigator,
    screen5: Screen5Navigator,
}
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      mode: 'modal',
      header: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        if (routeName === 'screen3') {
          return <Screen3Tab isFocused={focused} />;
        }
      },
    }),
```

4. Handle click manually inside a custom tab component `Screen3Tab` with TouchableWithoutFeedback & onPress. Inside Screen3Tab component:

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onPress}>
    <Your custom tab component here />
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

5. Once you catch onPress dispatch redux event

```
  onPress = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'NAVIGATION_NAVIGATE', payload: {
      key: 'screen3',
      routeName: 'screen3',
    }})
  }
```

6. Handle dispatched event using [Navigation Service](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html). I'm using `redux-saga` for it

```
  NavigationService.navigate(action.payload);
```

A bit complicated but works.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a better solution based on [this github issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1576#issuecomment-392918395).
You just have to add in the specific tab configuration, in your case screen3 the event navigationOptions(you already had it), you were pretty close, but, you had to receive the navigation as a parameter, because there isn't any context for `this` as you were using it. To correct the first code that you wrote I would change it to this and it would work:

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }) => {
    navigation.navigate("screen3Modal");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

what can be done is to prevent default action of tab press event and navigate to your desired screen with desired animation.

In my case, i wanted to open a modal in iOS in presentation style which came from iOS 13. what I did was prevent the default action like below

```
   <Tab.Screen name="screen1" 
    component={ EmptyScreen } // empty screen becuase I want nothing to present here so it was a component that returns null which is given bellow   
    listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
      tabPress: e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigation.navigate('modalscreen');
      },
    })} />


const EmptyScreen = () => {
  return null
}
```

'modelscreen' used in above code is from a navigation stack which looks like bellow. Tab navigator for Tab.Screen in the above code is
one of the screen in **otherstacknavigation** which is used in the navigation below.

```
const MainStack = ({ initialRoute }) => {
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator 
            initialRouteName="otherstacknavigation" 
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                gestureEnabled: true,
                cardOverlayEnabled: true,
                ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS
            }}>
        <Stack.Screen name='modalscreen' 
                      component={modalscreen}
                      options={{
                          headerShown: false
                      }} />
        <Stack.Screen name='otherstacknavigation' 
                      component={otherstacknavigation}
                      initialParams={{ initialRoute: initialRoute }}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default MainStack;
```

you can import **TransitionPresets** like bellow;

```
    import { createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack'
```

So, in my case, i have first main stack navigator which is MainStack above. It has another stack navigator which is otherstacknavigation in above MainStack. That otherstacknavigation has a screen whose component is Tab navigator. and Tab.Screen in above code is from that Tab Navigator. Now, from one of the tab from this tab navigator, i am navigating to 'modelscreen' which is in MainStack. I had to create this MainStack navigator just to achieve this features otherwise my code would start from otherstacknavigation. Because, ModalPresentationIOS can only be applied to stack level not screen level.

I am using react-navigation-5.* and i think it has answered multiple questions that can arise in such situation.